# How to append 2D array to 2D array with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, push

With Google Apps Script, I like to add a 2D array to the end of an existing  2D array.  But the following codes returned a 3D array with another nest inside, like “ [['AAPL', 'Strong'], ['MSFT', 'Strong'], ***[***[  'TSLA', 'Weak'], ['VZ', 'Neutral']***]***]”.  I want the 2D output, like [['AAPL', 'Strong'], ['MSFT', 'Strong'], ['TSLA', 'Weak'], ['VZ', 'Neutral']].  What should be changed in the codes!  Thank you for any guidance!

```
function test() {
  var data1 = [['AAPL', 'Strong'], ['MSFT', 'Strong']];
  var data2 = [['TSLA', 'Weak'], ['VZ', 'Neutral']];
  var output = data1;
  output.push(data2);
  console.log(output);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var output = data1.concat(data2);
```

Reference:

[Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)